# Converting from an interface to an object that implements the interface?

Tags: c#

I have an interface which is implemented by several different objects.  What I am trying to do is write a method in c# that will accept the interface object as a parameter and convert this parameter to an object that it implements so i don't have to write the same function for several different types.  Such as:

Class UnappliedCashDetails implements interface ITransactionDetail.

Constructor for ISSBatch:

```
public ISSBatch(List<ITransactionDetail> details)
```

public static ISSBatch GetNextReceiptBatch()
{
     List`<UnappliedCashDetail>` details = new List`<UnappliedCashDetail>`();

```
    /`*`some code here to populate my list`*`/            

    return = new ISSBatch(details);
```

}

C# does not like this.  Am i trying to use the interface wrong or just not casting correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `List<UnappliedCashDetail>` to a constructor that accepts `List<ITransactionDetail>`. `UnappliedCashDetail` may very well implement `ITransactionDetail`, but this type of variance is not supported by C#. Consider that inside the constructor (or any other method) you could attempt to add an instance of `SomeOtherTransactionDetail` to your details list, except that the details list should *really* only accept `UnappliedCashDetail`, as per its declaration.

To make your code work, you need to change your declaration

```
List<ITransactionDetail> details = new List<ITransactionDetail>();      
/* some code here to populate my list */                  
return new ISSBatch(details);
```

Or you could simply change your constructor to accept `IEnumerable<ITransactionDetail>`, in which case your original `List<UnappliedCashDetail>` declaration would work. Variance is supported for `IEnumerable<T>` (note: C# 4), since it is just a sequence and cannot be added to, deleted from, etc., so there's no possibility of trying to add an `AppliedCashDetail` instance to a sequence of `UnappliedCashDetail` objects.